# Core Data: Self referencing table

Tags: iphone, core-data, self-reference

I have an Entity in my Core Data model that contains a reference to itself. i.e. A Page can have a child collection of pages. When compiling i get the warning:

"Page.pages -- to-many relationship does not have an inverse:  this is an advanced setting (no object can be in multiple destinations for a specific relationship)"

Now I have read that core data requires an inverse relationship to maintain integrity and would like to provide this. I don't mind my data model being changed it is an early stage of development. What is an appropriate way of dealing with this situation?

[image]

Comment: Well, if the warning is that `Pages.pages` doesn't have an inverse relationship, have you tried adding an inverse relationship?  (Maybe `Pages.parent`?)

Comment: (self.feels.silly) exactly what i need, write it as an answer.

Comment: I don't need to do anything with inverse relationship, and no warning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(By request of @Aran)

Well, if the warning is that Pages.pages doesn't have an inverse relationship, have you tried adding an inverse relationship? (Maybe Pages.parent?)

Answer (score 0):

Select the pages relationship and set the inverse relationship to pages also.

edit: nvm thats if a page has more than one parent.